# I'm missing a term for sensitivity to language

Tags: single-word-request

There is a German word I have lost track of: means a sensitivity to nuances of meaning in other languages. Can someone remind me of this word?

Answer (score 8):

[*Sprachgefühl*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sprachgef%C3%BChl) is the word you are looking for.